# Possible to use /%monthname%/ in my permalink structure without using a plugin?

Tags: permalinks

I need to use the following permalink structure so that when I launch the website, the urls will be the same as they were before (moving from a non-wordpress site):

```
   /blog/posts/%year%/%monthname%/%postname%/
```

Is this possible without a plugin?

Comment: is the single.php template included in your theme?

Comment: Just updated with more info on the issue...

Comment: Support for specific plugin is off-topic here. Please consult with the related plugin support.

Comment: @Nilambar - I understand. Now I'm just curious if I can achieve the desired permalink structure without a plugin.